# Why do these two approaches to calculating the MSE gradient in R not give the same result?

Tags: r, matrix, statistics, gradient, matrix-multiplication

I'm experimenting with approaches to speeding up the calculation of the MSE gradient function. I thought a good way to save time would be to precalculate some of the matrix operations, which I've attempted in the function  `mse_grad_2` below. However, when I compare to a naive function the results differ (only by a very small amount, but I want to figure out why they aren't exactly the same).

```
set.seed(1)
y <- rnorm(10)
X <- matrix(rnorm(10*15), ncol=15, nrow=10)
beta <- rnorm(15)

mse_grad <- function(y, X, input, n) {
  r <- -(1/n)*t(X) %*% (y - X %*% input)
  return(r)
}

mse_grad_2 <- function(XTY, XTX, input, n) { 
  r <- -(1/n)*(XTY - XTX %*% input)
  return(r)
}

mean(mse_grad(y, X, beta, 10) - mse_grad_2(t(X) %*% y, t(X) %*% X, beta, 10))
# [1] 4.810966e-17
```

Comment: These are numerically equal for all intents & purposes: `4.810966e-17 < .Machine$double.eps` should (almost certainly, depending on your system) be `TRUE`.

Comment: I just ran this 1M times and got quantiles [9.2e-16, -6.7e-17, 0, 6.7e-17, 8.4e-16], so it oscillates normally around zero mostly within machine precision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to finite-precision arithmetic issues (see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic). For the same reasons

```
0.3 == 0.2 + 0.1
[1] FALSE
```

See below:

```
options(digits = 22)
0.3
[1] 0.2999999999999999888978
0.2
[1] 0.2000000000000000111022
0.1
[1] 0.1000000000000000055511
0.2 + 0.1
[1] 0.3000000000000000444089
```

Comment: Its not the same reason. 3 is definiteluy not equal to 2-1=1. you mean to have `0.3 == 0.2 + 0.1`

Comment: @Onyambu - you are right, I am sorry for my typo (I already corrected my original reply).